# how to get rows which begin with A(capital letter)?

Tags: sql-server-2008

how could I select rows that begin with capatil latter A
I've used this but it won't work

```
select name from myTable

where name like 'A%'
```

but the selected rows began with a (lower case ) and A (upper case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`select name from myTable
   where name like 'A%'
   COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`

where the ...`CS`... means Case-Sensitive.